# Sort a list by reference C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a `List<Unit>` where `Unit` contains `Name` and `Value`. In this object I store information about apparel sizes `Name` contains size names (S,M,L,XL..) and `Value` contains the quantity of that size.

This unit list is contained from a database, but the list comes in random order, so in the liste it might be like this:

```
Unit(M,3)
Unit(S,1)
Unit(XXL,2)
Unit(L,2)
```

I would like to sort the list so that it become more like this:

```
Unit(S,1)
Unit(M,3)
Unit(L,2)
Unit(XXLL,2)
```

I cant order on the string `ASCE` or `DESC` since it `M` comes before `S` and so on.
Then I thought I might create an reference Array with the correct order (XXS,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,XXXL), but how can I sort my list according to the reference.

Or are there other clever ways of doing this?

**Update**

Thanks for all good answers, I landed on the `Enum` solution, and it finally looks like this:

```
public class Unit
{
    public Unit()
    {
    }

    public Unit(string name, int value)
    {
        Value = value;
        SizeCode = AssignSizeCode(name);
    }

    public SizeCode SizeCode { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    private SizeCode AssignSizeCode(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "XXS":
                return SizeCode.XXS;
            case "XS":
                return SizeCode.XS;
            case "S":
                return SizeCode.S;
            case "M":
                return SizeCode.M;
            case "L":
                return SizeCode.L;
            case "XL":
                return SizeCode.XL;
            case "XXL":
                return SizeCode.XXL;
            case "XXXL":
                return SizeCode.XXXL;
            default:
                return SizeCode.Unknown;
        }
    }

}

public enum SizeCode
{
    XXS = 1,
    XS = 2,
    S = 3,
    M = 4,
    L = 5,
    XL = 6,
    XXL = 7,
    XXXL = 8,
    Unknown = 9
}
```

And I sort it like this:

```
units = units.OrderBy(x => (int)x.SizeCode).ToList();
```

Any comments, or things I can improve?

Comment: Normally apparel size is either an enum or generated from a stored range that includes other data relevant to the size, ie: chest size etc. That would have a numeric value that can be sorted against or a simple enum... public enum ApparelSize { XXS = 0, XS = 1, S = 2 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a enum

```
public enum Size
    {
        Small = 1,
        Medium = 2,
        // etc 

    }
```

Then you can convert the enum value in Unit class to int and sort by the integer value.

Comment: This is a good answer - `S` and `XXL` etc are simply text representations of the size and any sorting should not be done directly on this text (it should be on the enum or int that is used internally to represent the size).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `Enum` solution, I have updated my question with my final code. Please review it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I consider you should have OrderIndex column in your database and sort by that column.

the dirty way is to have your own class with interface : IComparer or do the same as delegate for sorting.

Check ICompararer in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx

Comment: I guess the OrderIndex would be a good idea, but I must clarify that the result is not comming directly from a SQL database, but directly from a ERP system. So I cant really add that column to the ERP system.

Comment: Your answer should be the other way round - IComparer is a good solution and ordering column on the database is a slight hack. To make a good answer that earns up votes you should either give an example of the IComparer or link to some doco about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what MSDN suggest [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx):

```
// First, declare a few classes that implement the IComparer interface.
public class CompareShirtSize : IComparer<string>
{
    // Because the class implements IComparer, it must define a 
    // Compare method. The method returns a signed integer that indicates 
    // whether s1 > s2 (return is greater than 0), s1 < s2 (return is negative),
    // or s1 equals s2 (return value is 0). This Compare method compares strings. 
    public int Compare(string size1, string size2)
    {
        // Do size comarison here
        return ConvertSizeToInt(size1) - ConvertSizeToInt(size2);
    }

    private int ConvertSizeToInt(string size)
    {
      switch (size)
      {
        case "XXS":
            return 1;
        case "XS":
            return 2;
        case "S":
            return 3;
        case "M":
            return 4;
        case "L":
            return 5;
        default:
           // some error handling
       }
}


// The following method tests the Compare methods defined in the previous classes.
public static void OrderByIComparer()
{
    List<Unit> units;

     // Sort the elements of the array alphabetically.
    var sortedList = units.OrderBy(unit => unit.Size, new CompareShirtSize ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Size` property of type `int` in your class `Unit`. Then sort your list using this `Size` property.

```
public class Unit1
{
    public Unit1(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;

        switch (this.Name)
        {
            case "XXS":
                this.Size = 1;
                break;
            case "XS":
                this.Size = 2;
                break;
            case "S":
                this.Size = 3;
                break;
            case "M":
                this.Size = 4;
                break;
            case "L":
                this.Size = 5;
                break;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Unit1> list1 = new List<Unit1>();
    list1.Add(new Unit1("XS") { Value = 1 });
    list1.Add(new Unit1("M") { Value = 1 });
    list1.Add(new Unit1("S") { Value = 1 });
    list1.Add(new Unit1("L") { Value = 1 });

    var sortedList = list1.OrderBy(z => z.Size).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use a Comparison Delegate. Firstly, make a function that just assigns a number to every size and then use that for comparison:

(I am not sure whether your sizes are stored as a String as an enum; but I would recommend storing them as an enum with the ordinal numbers in order of the sizes, increasing or decreasing. This will help make your comparison delegate faster and simpler).

```
public class ShirtSizeCompare {
    private static int getIndex(Unit x) {
        if(x == Null) { return -1; }

        if(x.size == "S") {
            return 0;
        } else if(x.size == "M") {
            return 1;
        }

        ///...
    }            

    private static int CompareShirts(Unit x, Unit y) {
        int _x = getIndex(x);
        int _y = getIndex(y);

        if(_x < _y) {
            return -1;
        } else if(_x == _y) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, simply use the `Comparison` delegate to sort the list:

```
List<Unit> unitList;
unitList.sort(CompareShirts);
```

The comparison delegate basically takes as input two variables `x` and `y` and returns:

```
<0 (if x < y)
>0 (if x > y)
0  (if x == y)
```

Check this page for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx