# sort Apparel Sizes in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSArray with values XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL in random order.

How would I go about sorting this properly in Objective-C?

I looked at this code for a starting point but I am having zero luck:

[Sort a list by reference C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358635/sort-a-list-by-reference-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

If you create an ordered set to act as a "reference" order, you can then use the `NSMutableSet` method `intersectSet:` to create an ordered list from your array:

**Edit** [David Rönnqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608157/david-ronnqvist) just made a good point. Need to check for multiple instances of the same 'size'.

```
//This is my "reference" set, declared only once in my class
NSOrderedSet *reference = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"XS",@"S",@"M",@"L",@"XL", nil];

//This is the array I'm trying to sort, which may or may not contain all the sizes
NSArray *randomArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"XL", @"XS", @"M", @"XS", nil];

//Create a mutable ordered set from my reference
NSMutableOrderedSet *ordered = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:reference];

//Interset with the array
[ordered intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:randomArray]];

//Look for multiple instances of the same size
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *sortedSize in ordered){

    for (NSString *randomSize in randomArray){
        if ([randomSize isEqualToString:sortedSize]){
            [result addObject:randomSize];
        }
    }
}
```

My result from the above was an array containing:

`@"XS", @"XS", @"M", @"XL"`

If you were going to create a method that did this, you could also compare the count of `ordered` to the array you were sorting, and if they were equal don't bother with the iteration.

Comment: How would that work if one of the values appeared more than once?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a reference array, containing the values in the correct order, then sorting the input array based on the index at which each element appears in the reference array. To whit:

```
NSArray *reference = @[ @"XS", @"S", @"M", @"L", @"XL", @"XXL" ];
NSArray *inputArray = @[ @"S", @"M", @"L", @"L", @"M", @"S", @"XXL", @"S" ];

NSArray *sortedArray = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSUInteger aindex = [reference indexOfObject:a];
    NSUInteger bindex = [reference indexOfObject:b];
    if (aindex > bindex)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    if (aindex < bindex)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
```

This works, but it suffers the downside of calling `indexOfObject:` much more often than we'd like. If we assume `sortedArrayUsingComparator` uses [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) then we're looking at O(N*logN) comparisons, with each comparison calling `indexOfObject:` twice. `indexOfObject:` in turn runs in O(N) time. Overall then, not good.

There are a couple of ways you could improve this. You could for example use the [decorate-sort-undecorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) idiom. Here you pre-calculate the sort keys for your array elements (the reference array indices in this case), decorate the array elements with them, sort using them, then strip them back off.

In this case it's easier to *translate* values to their indices in the reference array (rather than decorating them), then translate back (rather than undecorating). Same idea though. Here's how it looks:

```
// First get the indices
NSMutableArray *indices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[inputArray count]];
for (id elem in inputArray) {
    [indices addObject:@([reference indexOfObject:elem])];
}

// Then sort the list of indices
[indices sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" 
                                                              ascending:YES]]];

// Finally, translate indices back to source elements
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[inputArray count]];
for (NSNumber *index in indices) {
    [results addObject:reference[[index unsignedIntegerValue]]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

The other way you could tackle it is by making the reference array a reference dictionary instead, with values ("XS", "S", etc) mapped to their sort orders (0, 1...). This is effectively the same as my first solution, but with the reference array indices pre-computed and stored in a dictionary. Unlike `indexOfObject:`, which runs in O(N) time, looking up a dictionary value by its key runs in O(1) time.

This would have been unthinkably ugly before object literals came along, but now it's quite elegant. For a small reference set this would be my preferred option.

```
NSDictionary *reference = @{ 
    @"XS":  @0, 
    @"S":   @1, 
    @"M":   @2,
    @"L":   @3,
    @"XL":  @4,
    @"XXL": @5
};

NSArray *inputArray = @[ @"S", @"M", @"L", @"L", @"M", @"S", @"XXL", @"S" ];

NSArray *sortedArray = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    return [reference[a] compare:reference[b]];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way will consist to use the sortedArrayUsingComparator method:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmpt
```

Your code will look like the following then:

```
 NSArray * randomArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"S", @"L", @"M", @"L", @"XL", @"M", nil];

 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                         init];
 [ dictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"S"];
 [ dictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"M"];
 [ dictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"L"];
 [ dictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:@"XL"];

 NSArray *sortedArray = [randomArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: 
    ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

        NSNumber *value1 = [dictionary objectForKey:obj1];
        NSNumber *value2 = [dictionary objectForKey:obj2];

        return [value1 compare:value2];
    }];


   for (NSString *item in sortedArray)
   {
       NSLog(@"%@", item);
   }
```

This will print to the console:
S
M
M
L
L
XL

As you see instead of using an `enum` mentioned in the C# solution i am using a NSDictionnary that contain `NSNumber` so i can directly use the `compare` method in the `comparison` block.

Comment: Seems like the root problem here though is how to efficiently compare these arbitrary strings.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thanks - I actually prefer to use the sortedArrayUsingComparator for the sorting otherwise i will have to write a category for the NSString